# How to increase simultaneous requests for LIGHTTPD

Tags: mysql, php, lighttpd, fastcgi

I have Red Hat 6 and I've installed Lighttpd + MySQL and at the moment in getting 500 internal server error, logs shows that I have arround 2000 requests / sec, while as soon as requests drop below 1000 websites starts to load again.

I wonder how can I increase this limit.

My machine have 20 CPU's, 128GB RAM, so I doubt it's machine problem :S

I use FastCGI, while website is in **PHP** language.

Comment: You need to give us a bit more. I you use MySQL you probably have a dynamic laguage. PHP? Python? Ruby? Connected via FastCGI over. TCP? File Socket? Add a few error lines of your log. Add a few important config parts (workers).

Comment: I'm curious about the mathematics -- how did you end up with exactly 20 CPUs?

Answer (score 1):

**Your bottleneck is PHP, not Lighttpd.**

What are you testing, a static page with a `echo "Hello World"` or something more complex?

*And just because you have 20 cores and 128GB of RAM doesn't mean anything if the userspace apps and OS aren't configured to take advantage of it*,

Answer (score 1):

Does this mean that you did not configure fastcgi at all?

`PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN` and `PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS` should be the values you tweak as soon as you set your hands on a new fcgi server. Do not that setting max children to a very high level may very well prove better in a short benchmark but result in your currently running scripts consuming more than your maximum memory at some point - so when you benchmark - do it with real scripts and keep it up for a bit while you monitor the status of the machine.

When you also haven't given any information about the scripts you run - it's impossible to say where the bottleneck could be. It could be I/O wait for MySQL by badly utilizing caches, or heavy/badly written php scripts, or alot of other stuff.